# How to block range of incoming IPs in Windows Advanced Firewall

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, firewall

I wanna block incoming connections from **13.54.X.X**.
Under the "Scope" > "This IP address range input" input boxes *(From and To)*, do i write:

**13.54.0.0** to **13.54.255.255**

**OR** do i have to create individual rules:

```
13.54.0.0 to 13.54.0.255
13.54.1.0 to 13.54.1.255
13.54.2.0 to 13.54.2.255
13.54.3.0 to 13.54.3.255
```

?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First calculate the sub-network CIDR notation. In **13.54.0.0 to 13.54.255.255** IPv4 range, the first two octates are constant (the network prefix) and the remaining last two octates are variable (host addressing). So the bit-length of the prefix is (32-16)=16. And the CIDR notation is **13.54.0.0/16**.

There are three ways to block that IP range.

1. With Firewall Control Panel:: Open Windows Firewall control panel with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type **WF.msc**. Click on Inbound Rules > New Rules > Custom > All Programs > Protocol type: Any > Add remote IP address (see below) > Check Block the Connection > Profile: select all > Name.

[image: Firewall_New_Rule]

Add remote IP addresses:: Click on *'This IP address'* radio button in remote IP section. Type **13.54.0.0/16** below *'this IP address or subnet'* and then OK. Now your inbound rule is ready.

[image: Add_IP_Address]

2. **With Administrator Command Prompt::** Type this command `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="New_Rule" Dir=In Action=Block RemoteIP=13.54.0.0/16`

[image: CMD_Add_rule]

3. **With Administrator Powershell::** Type this command `New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Inbound -DisplayName "New_Rule" -Name "New_Rule" -RemoteAddress 13.54.0.0/16 -Action Block`

[image: Powershell_Add_rule]

Further reading::

- [Wikipedia:Subnetwork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork)
- [Wikipedia:Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)
- [Technet:New-NetFirewallRule](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554908(v=wps.630).aspx)
- [Technet:netsh advfirewall](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd734783(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_3_add)

Comment: BTW, you are blocking IPs associated with Amazon Corporate Services which have IP range 13.54.0.0 - 13.55.255.255. Source:: [ARIN whois](https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-13-54-0-0-1)

Comment: Yes, most of those IPs are used by the video game Overwatch for multiplayer. Those IPs are in USA but im in SEA so I get very high ping when the game starts.

Answer (score 7):

PowerShell also supports ranges and lists if it doesn't fall into a certain subnet mask.

```
New-NetFirewallRule -Name "Block Rule (in)" `
                -Description "Bad IP'S" `
                -DisplayName "Block Rule (in)" `
                -Enabled True `
                -Profile Any `
                -Direction Inbound `
                -Action Block `
                -RemoteAddress ("13.54.0.0-13.54.0.255",
                                    "13.54.1.0-13.54.1.255",
                                    "13.54.2.0-13.54.2.255",
                                    "13.54.3.0-13.54.3.255" )
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Create a Single Firewall Rule Using a Subnet Mask

You can create a single firewall rule to block the IP range `13.54.0.0 to 13.54.255.255` using the `/16` mask like this:

```
13.54.0.0/16
```

The portion after the `/` is the *subnet mask* which specifies how many bits of the specified address should be examined to determine if a connection's IP address matches the rule.

In your case it's easy to figure this out. You want to match addresses based only on the first two octets (**13.54.**x.x) of the IP address. An octet contains 8 bits, so two octets equals 16 bits or a mask of `/16`.

Find out more [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_mask) about using a mask of bits to indicate which parts of an IP are matched.

Answer (score 1):

Scope > Remote IP address > This IP Range > From:  13.54.0.0 > To:  13.54.0.255

Then add the rest of them in the same rule.

This will work in windows firewall, however it would take a long time to add each one. Definitely not efficient.  In this scenario Twisty's CIDR solution would be best.